# How to cite from a book with more authors?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Some books start each chapter with a short inspirational quote from some famous person e.g.

> Chapter 1.
>
> "I think, therefore I am"
>
> -René Descartes

I would like to do the same and I found the perfect quote, but the book it is from has three authors. What should I write on the bottom of the quote?

Comment: How about: "-X, Y and Z in their book *ABC*"

Comment: But what if Y and Z have nothing to do with that particular sentence? Is it ok anyway? Did you see an example of such a citation?

Comment: Ambrose Bierce in his "The Devil's Dictionary" jokes about Descartes quotation by saying **I think that I think, therefore I think that I am!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember the guiding principle of maximum ease in following a reference. If you don't know which author, cite primarily to the book.

> From "Book title", by x,y, and z

In fact, even if there is only one author, it is good to cite the book.